# Serialization in C# doesn't work

Tags: c#, serialization

I've got a serialized object *AgentUP*

```
         [Serializable]
     public class AgentUp
    {
        String agentName;
         public String agentNameProperty
        {
            get { return agentName; }
            set { agentName = value; }
        }
     }
```

and method *SerializeAgentUpToXml* to serialize it

```
       static public string SerializeAgentUpToXml(AgentUp arg)
    {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AgentUp));
        serializer.Serialize(writer, arg);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
```

I try to serialize and send the object in *sendAgent()*

```
            public void sendAgent()
    {
        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

        int handlerPort = 600;
        IPAddress handlerIp = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        NetworkStream clientStream;

        try
        {
            client.Connect(handlerIp, handlerPort);
            clientStream = client.GetStream();

            SerializationAndData.AgentUp agentUp = new SerializationAndData.AgentUp();
            agentUp.agentNameProperty = "sth";

            byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes(SerializationAndData.SerializeAgentUpToXml(agentUp));

            clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            clientStream.Flush();
            clientStream.Close();
            UpdateRichTextBox("works");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            UpdateRichTextBox("doesn't work");
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Close();
        }
    }
```

I debugged it and it connects, but the exception occurs in the line:

```
       serializer.Serialize(writer, arg);
```

Any ideas? I'd be very grateful.

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: Well, what **does** happen? Also: [Serializable] is unrelated to XmlSerializer

Comment: The exception messages from XmlSerializer are exceptionally detailed if you step into each .InnerException: so - what does it say?